# Using cell values according to the time of the day

Tags: excel, function, time, hour

I need to create a spreadsheet that should pull data from a cell according to the time of the day.

In the column "A" I have all the hours of the day, ranging from 0 to 23; in the column "F", I have series of arbitrary numbers related to a use behavior I am tracking.

I'd like to create a formula that, for example, at 4PM, show me the value of the "F" column related to the number "16". Ex: at midnight, get the "F" column value related to A1 (which is 0, because it's midnight), then F1 = X (where X is the arbitrary number at line 1).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   =vlookup(HOUR(NOW()),$a$1:$f$24,6,0)
```

You were already half way there. `NOW()` gives you the time, `Hour` gives you the hour of now and vlookup returns the value in the 6th column next to your searched value.

Comment: Balinti, thanks for the reply. I'm afraid I wasn't clear enough:

Comment: In the column "A" I have all the hours of the day, ranging from 0 to 23; in the column "F", I have series of arbitrary numbers related to a use behavior I am tracking.

Comment: I'd like to create a formula that, for example, at 4PM, show me the value of the "F" column related to the number "16".

Comment: Ex: at midnight, get the "F" column value related to A1 (which is 0, because it's midnight), then F1 = X (where X is the arbitrary number at line 1).

Comment: Yes.. I edited my answer, please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks, Balinti: I am still lost somehow. I receive the error message:
"Error
Did not find value '12' in VLOOKUP evaluation."

If I change the range to '$a$2:$f$25', to not include the headers of the columns, I ger the error message

Error
Did not find value '12' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

What am I missing? Thnks in advance

Comment: Is A13 populated with the number 12? maybe it is shown as text? try to enter 12 manually as number.

Comment: Cell has numbers already and still get error message. If I write the value or the cell, it works. If not, syas that the value wasn't found. I've copied here so u can see it: https://goo.gl/pbIIW8

Comment: Now it is working. The problem was the numbers were not stored as numbers on your spread sheet.